# Dynamic charts from pivot

Tags: excel, macos, charts, pivot-table, excel-2011

I have a data set that I am using as an input to a pivot table. I have transformed that data set into a table, so that every-time I add something to the data set, the pivot gets updated automatically. I have also added a line of code, so that every-time a user clicks on the sheet containing the pivot table, the table gets refreshed automatically. Now I need to have a chart (linked to the pivot table) that updates automatically every-time the pivot refreshes (like rows or columns also increase/decrease).

Comment: Why should you base the chart on the pivot table rather than the source table? Also, you can set the pivot chart to update automatically the same way as you did with the pivot table.

Comment: The reason I am basing my chart on the pivot and not the base data is because I am aggregating and calculating some new things in the pivot. So pivot is just making it easier. I am currently using excel 2011 on mac so there is no option of pivot chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a dynamic named range in order to get the chart data to update automatically. Without knowing what your data looks like, I'll just provide you with a generic version assuming your data is in A1:C5.

```
=OFFSET(A1;0;0;COUNT(A:A);3)
```

This will create a range that is 3 columns wide and goes until the last row with data in column A.